# RadiobuttonList's Item's Text to show Count and retrieve using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have RadioButtonList

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoRating" runat="server" 
                     RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                     Height="33px" Width="249px">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Brilliant</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Interesting</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Poor</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I want to show the number of people selected (count) Brilliant or Interesting or Poor
such as " 0 Brilliant(56) 0 Interesting(88) 0 Poor(12)" 0 represent radiobutton

I want to show this count on PageLoad event

AND

select COUNT(Rating) from CommentTable where Rating = 'Interesting'

It is SQL Query but i want LINQ Query

Plz help me i am new to this Field..

Comment: What do you have? Did you build your Entity model or anything? If so, tell us which entities do you have and their properties.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a simple Linq version of that SQL you need... then you just want to use something like:

```
// select COUNT(Rating) from CommentTable where Rating = 'Interesting'
var result = db.Comments
              .Where(comment => comment.Rating == "Interesting")
              .Count();
```

However, I think you can do much, much better if you spend some time to think about the SQL and about the Linq (e.g. you should be able to fetch all three counts with one query using a `Group By`). If what you want is a good introduction to Linq and/or the Entity Framework, then try some links like:

- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1237071
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567.aspx
- http://odetocode.com/articles/737.aspx

Take your time and you'll learn to love Linq - it really is superb!